# Error "'Quiver' object has no attribute 'shape'"

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using the Python Quiver function to combine u-velocity and v-velocity values into a vector map. I have semi-successfully combined the two arrays by using the quiver function within the colormesh() function, and my code returns a B&W plot of the data, but I get an error message "'Quiver' object has no attribute 'shape'". The data plot also seems to not allow the landmass/ocean commands to plot (or if I put those commands before the colormesh() command, then the quiver() command doesn't work). Also, I can't seem to add color or size to the quiver arrows. Why am I still getting sort of successful plotting, if I'm getting this error message? How can I fix it? I tried making a quiver array and then just plotting the name of that in the colormesh(), but that didn't work, either.

Thank you!!

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-120,llcrnrlat=32,urcrnrlon=-116,urcrnrlat=35,
        resolution='l',projection='stere',
        lat_0=32.5,lon_0=-117.)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.figtext(.45,.15,'Figure 1. Avg. velocity from CORDC HF Radar avg. June 1, 2013',fontsize=12,ha='center')

x, y = m(lon,lat)# define color map
cmap = plt.cm.hsv


cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,quiver(lon[0:230],lat[0:230],u_nanmean_mask,v_nanmean_mask),shading='gouraud',cmap=cm.RdYlBu,vmin=-0.10,vmax=0.12)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='#989865',lake_color='w')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='w')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81.,5.),labels=[0,1,1,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,5.),labels=[1,0,0,1])
```

Comment: Why are you passing the object returned by `quiver` to `pcolormesh`?

Comment: That was the only way I could get the dataset at all plotted onto the map. When I tried to create a separate quiver plotting step, and then incorporate that into Quiver, I got a blank plot (e.g. making:    Q = m.quiver(lon[0:230],lat[0:230],u_nanmean_mask,v_nanmean_mask) )

Comment: So, you should ask a question about why that did not work.  What you have here is not close to the correct usage of `pcolormesh`.  Please include synthetic data in your example so that it is copy-paste runnable.